# Creating new virtualenv 1.11.5 failed with setuptools issue

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

It worked a few days ago but creating a new vertualenv today causes this failure.

Tried installation of python-setuptools separately, also failed with same issue.  It is on Mac OS.

```
   mac:django bgbb$ virtualenv vnv
New python executable in vnv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
Complete output from command /Users/bgbb/Developer/django/vnv/bin/python -c "import sys,   pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking setuptools
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
 requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
do_download,
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req.py", line 1364, in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 640, in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/util.py", line 621, in unpack_file
unzip_file(filename, location, flatten=not filename.endswith(('.pybundle', '.whl')))
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/util.py", line 491, in unzip_file
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 766, in __init__
self._RealGetContents()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 807, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
 BadZipfile: File is not a zip file

 Storing debug log for failure in /Users/bgbb/.pip/pip.log
 ----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
   load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11.5', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
   symlink=options.symlink)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
   install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
   'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
   % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
 OSError: Command /Users/bgbb/Developer/django/vnv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip;   sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 2
```

Answer (score 4):

lots of posts about this issue, downgrading  to [virtualenv 1.10.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.10.1) seems to be a fix.

[github venev issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/524)

Comment: Per https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/129/assertionerror-egg-info-pkg-info-is-not-a, pip-1.5.2 and virtualenv-1.11.2 will contain that fix.  Here is my versions of pip and virtualenv pip --version
pip 1.5.4 
virtualenv 1.11.5

Comment: I was just about to ask if you had, 1.11.5 is a May release I think.

Comment: Installed 1.11.2 and worked. The virtualenv 1.11.5 (May 3 release) regressed again clearly.

Comment: For me, 1.10.1 works but 1.11.2 and 1.11.5 exhibit the same broken behavior.